# Function that checks if dates of multiple formats is within range

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have a range with variables that look like this:

`startDate = 2015-12-01`
`endDate = 2015-12-31`

I have another date I need to check is within range that looks like this:

`dateToCheck = 01/15/2016`

I'm trying to write a function which returns a true or false of whether the date is within range:

```
function dateInRange(date, startDate, endDate) {

}
```

In PHP you could convert any date string into a timestamp, I'm not sure how to do that in Javascript from multiple formats?

Comment: You can use [`.getTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime).

Comment: you can also convert them to string: YYYY-MM-DD and compare them that way, but doing with timestamps is better probably

Comment: You have [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) built-in, or there are libraries like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) that have more intelligent date parsers.

Comment: Date.parse won't work on 01/15/2016

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a function that parses the date and returns a Date object

```
function createDate(date) {
    if ( date.indexOf('-') !== -1 ) {
        var parts = date.split('-');
        return new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2]);
    } else if ( date.indexOf('/') !== -1 ) {
        var parts = date.split('/');
        return new Date(parts[2], parts[0]-1, parts[1]);
    } else {
        return new Date(date);
    }

}
```

Then you can parse the dates and do

```
function dateInRange(date, startDate, endDate) {

    return date > startDate && date < endDate;

}
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/qrhbr9en/)

Comment: return new Date(date) || 0; is not very useful, as it'll sometime return Date, sometimes integer 0

Comment: @Gavriel - it was just to return a number for the `>` comparison etc, and not the string `Invalid Date`

Comment: but the other returns return Date. Maybe you meant to return new Date(...).getTime() everywhere? Still why would a badly formatted date string need to mean 1970-01-01?

Comment: Comparing a date coerces the value to milliseconds anyway, there's no need for `getTime` here

Comment: And again, I returned `0`, as in the integer zero, not epoch, as that seemed better to me than returning the string `Invalid date`, but it really doesn't matter for this answer anyway, so I'll remove it as you don't seem to get why I added it.

Comment: Ok, better IMHO without, ESPECIALLY that it doesn't work (though it tricked me as well :) Try it: new Date('sdsfsd') || 0 will give you 'Invalid date', it's not an empty string so you will never get 0 anyway

Comment: Yes, I know, a string is "truthy", so it never really returns `0`

Comment: Just had to add `>=` and `<=` in order for it to include it in the range if it was only one day.